# Bosonic Gas vs Ideal Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, bosons, identical-particles

Bosonic Gases and Ideal Gases have these properties in common:

1. They are composed of
   indistinguishable particles.
2. The particles of both gases do not
   obey the Pauli Exclusion
   Principle.

As far as I know, the expression for thermodynamic probability  is determined based on these characteristics. However, the expression for thermodynamic probability is different in the case of a bosonic gas from how it is for an ideal gas.

Specifically, for a bosonic gas, it is:

$Ω_B = Π_i\frac{(g_i + n_i - 1)!}{(n_i)!(g_i - 1)!}$

while for an ideal gas, it is:

$Ω_I = Π_i \frac{g_i^{n_i}}{(n_i)!}$

But why are they different? It seems like the expression for thermodynamic probability should be the same in each
case.

I used the second expression to find the value of the constants $α$, $β$ in the distribution law expression to get:-

$α = \frac{-μ}{k_BT}$

$β = \frac{1}{k_BT}$

Comment: Could you clarify notation in your equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bosonic expression for $\Omega_i$ can be written

$$\Omega_i=\frac{(g_i-1+n_i)(g_i-1+n_i-1)(g_i-1+n_i-2)...(g_i-1+1)(g_i-1)!}{(n_i)!(g_i-1)!}=\frac{(g_i-1+n_i)(g_i-1+n_i-1)(g_i-1+n_i-2)...(g_i-1+1)}{(n_i)!}$$
In the top line there are now $n_i$ brackets multiplied together.

In the case of the ideal gas (low molecular concentration) we assume that

$$g_i\gg n_i.$$
Therefore each of the $n_i$ brackets in our last expression for $\Omega_i$ can be treated as equal simply to $g_i$. Hence, remembering that there are $n_i$ brackets multiplied together, we have
$$\Omega_i=\frac{(g_i)^{n_i}}{(n_i)!}$$
[With the same assumption, $g_i\gg n_i$, a Fermi gas has the same ideal gas limiting value for $\Omega_i$.]

Comment: You are saying both the expressions are equivalent. I checked in a calculator to get same value for the different expression by choosing different values for $g_i,n_i$.

Comment: Did you make $g_i\gg n_i$? And what did you get? Note that you need large numbers for both $n_i$ and $g_i$, which a calculator may not be able handle. Taking logs of both sides of the equation and using Stirling's formula will help.

Comment: for $g_i >> n_i$ both the expressions produce the same result. I took $g_i = n_i$ and the expressions produced different results.

Comment: Good! Numerical checks are re-assuring.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem actually lies here:

> As far as I know, the expression for thermodynamic probability is determined based on these characteristics.

> But why are they different? It seems like the expression for thermodynamic probability should be the same in each case.

The bosonic ideal gas and the classical (Maxwell-Boltzmann) ideal gas are simply different, so why did you think that the above characteristics alone are sufficient to identify which type of system you are dealing with?

Gibbs's solution to his paradox is a last minute hack, and so the resulting fixed system is still classical in general nature, other than taking into account this important quantum property. The properly correct way to solve Gibbs's paradox is to actually handle quantum particle indistinguishability properly, and that leads us to only bosonic and fermionic gases. The classical ideal gas is but the high temperature limit of both of them. (And some other possible limits, but I cannot be bothered with the details right now.)

Comment: this means my second expression is just a "last-minute-hack" (approximate). Ideal gases should be treated like bosons and thus, bose-einstein statistics.

Comment: @naturallyIncosistent, the two characteristics can only affect the thermodynamic probability . What else can affect the thermodynamic probability? Please mention those

Comment: The fermionic ideal gas is still a correct ideal gas. Also, bosons and fermions are a general term, by that I mean you can include interactions, turning them into non-ideal, (actually, better than ideal, because they would fit real gases better).

Comment: In ideal gas there are no interactions.

Comment: The mistaken assumption that we can use classical logic (and probability arguments) rather than quantum logic (and probability and statistics) also affect the thermodynamic probability.

Comment: Why do you think I am unaware that ideal gases are, by definition, ignoring interactions? I am telling you to take a more general view of things than you currently are.

Comment: Actually, I used the second expression to derive two constants $α, β$ it matched the answer.

Comment: So, I was just checking the validity of the second expression.

Answer (score -1):

Bosonic gas is composed of *indistinguishable particles*, whereas *ideal gas* is of *identical particles*, distinguishable however by their positions (since we can follow the trajectory of each particle.)

An important consequence of of distinguishability by the particle position in phase space, is that the particle states are also distinguishable, and we cannot have two (classical) particles in the same state.

The difference in the equations is due to the fact that ideal gas is treated in non-degenerate limit (particle states are singly occupied), whereas when we speak of *boson gas*, we mean the same gas in the degenerate limit. This is the point made in @PhilipWood answer.

Comment: Well, but when calculating the partition function for the ideal gas we fiddle in a $1/N!$ because the particles are indistinguishable hence the label of each particle on the current trajectory can be reshuffled to describe the same microstate?

Comment: @AlmostClueless they can be reshuffled, but they cannot be in the same state (unlike bosons.)

Comment: @RogerVadim in an ideal gas the particles are indistinguishable to resolve the Gibbs Paradox.

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta The main point of my answer is that *distinguishable* and *identical* do not mean the same thing... although one may confuse the two terms when talking about ideal gas (i.e., not having in mind QM effects.) But see also my comment above.

Comment: @RogerVadim I think everyone agrees that identical and indistinguishable do not mean the same thing. Still, talking about the classical ideal gas when computing the partition function we do not exclude the overlap of the phase-space integrations between particles. Therefore we *do* take into account a microstate where two or more particles are in the same *classical* state. Don't we?

Comment: @AlmostClueless do you agree with *degenerate* vs. *non-degenerate* bose gas language? It means the same thing however. Yes, you do integrate over the same regions of space, but in the continuum limit the probability of hitting any particular point is zero. Once you discretize the space, you put only one particle in each cell. This is the case that the formulas in the OP and the other answer refer to.